# Facebook graph api empty data when getting user likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm using a Facebook application that get all user likes in order to check if a given page is liked using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID}/likes?access_token={MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Everything works fine for me and for the most part of the users, **except for some users**, that return this:

```
{
  "data": [

  ]
}
```

Why does it return an empty data? I already requested the authorization for **user_likes** in the application

Comment: @magadv Do you know any other way of getting user's likes

Answer (score 4):

Apps only have access to a user's public information.  Even with user_likes permission you will get no Likes data from a user that has set their Likes to private.

Comment: How can I try it? I'd like to remove my given permission in order to try the error, and then fix it. But I can't find my application even if I'm using it.

Comment: @VoodooMike: THANK YOU! You saved my day that was my issue :)