# Facebook Graph API - Getting mutual likes

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an issue when getting mutual likes with Facebook Graph API. The context is the following:

- userA is the requester from an iOS application
- userA and userB have granted "user_likes" permission both from the iOS app
- userA and userB are **not** Facebook friends

My app Swift code for this part is the following:

```
self.FBLoginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_birthday", "user_about_me", "user_likes"]
...
...
let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: userBFBid, parameters: ["fields": "context.fields(mutual_likes).limit(10)"])
graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("res: \(result)")
        }
    })
```

The result is the following:

```
res: {
  context =     {
    id = dXNlcl9jb250ZAXh0OgGQg20zLjrZAswOnuX6*******;
    "mutual_likes" =         {
        data =             (
        );
        summary =             {
            "total_count" = 0;
        };
    };
  };
  id = 101532998**********;
}
```

As you can see, the mutual likes are not returned.

I made the same request with userA and userC which **are Facebook friends**, and that **works correctly**, all their mutual likes are returned.

Again: userA, userB and userC have the app installed and granted the **user_likes** permission.

Any idea to fix it and to get mutual_likes with two users which are **not Facebook friends**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the issue.

First of all: user likes must be visible by **public** in FB user account privacy configuration to be accessible by the API **even if the `user_likes` permission is granted**.
Source: [Facebook graph api empty data when getting user likes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195443/facebook-graph-api-empty-data-when-getting-user-likes)

Secondly, if the users are **not** friends on Facebook, the request must also include the parameter `appsecret_proof` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests). So the request must be performed from your server and not from your app for safety reason. Source: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/101463963524794/

Hope that helps someone one day!